# Ifelse condition across multiple variables using paste0 function to call up variables

Tags: r

I want to use an ifelse condition across multiple variables using paste0("Var",c(1,3,5)) to call up variables.
Here is some data.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Var1 = sample(1:5,10,replace = T),
                 Var2 = sample(1:5,10,replace = T),
                 Var3 = sample(1:5,10,replace = T),
                 Var4 = sample(1:5,10,replace = T),
                 Var5 = sample(1:5,10,replace = T))
 df
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1     3    5    2    1    5
2     3    3    1    1    5
3     2    3    3    2    4
4     2    1    4    3    5
5     3    4    1    4    2
6     5    1    3    5    1
7     4    1    5    5    1
8     1    5    4    3    3
9     2    3    2    1    1
10    3    2    5    2    5
```

As an example, i'm interested in Var1, Var3, Var5. Using ifelse, if the value is equal to 4,5 the new variable is given value of 1, else 0.
I'm using code to get the variables I'm interested in.

```
paste0( "Var", c(1,3,5)  ) 
[1] "Var1" "Var3" "Var5"
```

I tried both of these, and know this doesn't work but is it possible to write a code that is similar to this

```
newvar <- ifelse( paste0("Var", c(1,3,5)) %in% c(4,5) , 1, 0) 
newvar <- ifelse( df[ , paste0( "Var", c(1:3)  )  ] %in% c(4,5) , 1, 0)
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

EDITED : Apologies if wasn't clear. I was making the ifelse across multiple variables to create a single variable. "newvar" is single variable, I didnte want to create the ifelse for each variable newvar1, newvar3, newvar5. It is any value of 4 or 5 in any of those variables, newvar is 1 or 0. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sapply:

```
v <- paste0("Var", c(1, 3, 5)) # or v <- c(1, 3, 5)
cbind(df, new = +sapply(df[v], `%in%`, 4:5))
```

giving:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 new.Var1 new.Var3 new.Var5
1     3    5    2    1    5        0        0        1
2     3    3    1    1    5        0        0        1
3     2    3    3    2    4        0        0        1
4     2    1    4    3    5        0        1        1
5     3    4    1    4    2        0        0        0
6     5    1    3    5    1        1        0        0
7     4    1    5    5    1        1        1        0
8     1    5    4    3    3        0        1        0
9     2    3    2    1    1        0        0        0
10    3    2    5    2    5        0        1        1
```

### Added

Regarding the comment below this answer try any of these.  They all use v defined in the next line except for the last solution.

```
v <- paste0("Var", c(1, 3, 5)) # or v <- c(1, 3, 5)
transform(df, newvar = do.call("pmax", lapply(df[v], `%in%`, 4:5)))

transform(df, newvar = apply(df[v] == 4 | df[v] == 5, 1, max))

transform(df, newvar = apply(df[v], 1, function(x) +any(x %in% 4:5)))

transform(df, newvar = pmax(Var1 %in% 4:5, Var3 %in% 4:5, Var5 %in% 4:5))
```

any of which give:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 newvar
1     3    5    2    1    5      1
2     3    3    1    1    5      1
3     2    3    3    2    4      1
4     2    1    4    3    5      1
5     3    4    1    4    2      0
6     5    1    3    5    1      1
7     4    1    5    5    1      1
8     1    5    4    3    3      1
9     2    3    2    1    1      0
10    3    2    5    2    5      1
```

Comment: Very useful but apologies if wasn't clear. I was making the ifelse across multiple variables to create a single variable. "newvar" is single variable, not than newvar1 newvar3, newvar5. I've edit original question. thanks

Comment: OK. Added 2 approaches in the Added section.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on the tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      c(Var1, Var3, Var5), 
      ~ifelse(.x %in% c(4, 5), 1, 0), 
      .names="new{.col}"
    )
  )
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 newVar1 newVar3 newVar5
1     3    5    2    1    5       0       0       1
2     3    3    1    1    5       0       0       1
3     2    3    3    2    4       0       0       1
4     2    1    4    3    5       0       1       1
5     3    4    1    4    2       0       0       0
6     5    1    3    5    1       1       0       0
7     4    1    5    5    1       1       1       0
8     1    5    4    3    3       0       1       0
9     2    3    2    1    1       0       0       0
10    3    2    5    2    5       0       1       1
```

The `across` function runs the function defined in its second argument on each of the columns defined by its first argument.  The `.names` argument is optional and provides names for the new columns (as opposed to overwriting the originals).  `{.col}` is a palceholder for the name of the current column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `base R`solution close to what OP tried:

```
df$newVar <- sapply(df[,c(1,3,5)], function(x) ifelse(x == 4|x == 5, 1, 0))
```

or, even closer:

```
df$newVar <- sapply(df[,c(1,3,5)], function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(4,5), 1, 0))
```

Comment: thanks for this, i can definetely use it but is there something simpler. Apologies if wasn't clear. I was making the ifelse across multiple variables to create a single variable. "newvar" is single variable rather than newvar1 newvar3, newvar5. I will edit original question. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting an error message to that. Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, newVar, value = list(Var1 = c(0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 10

Comment: Sorry, have edited the solution ...

Comment: close, it creates a newvar but it contains the 3 list variables. Thanks

Comment: There's no advantages to change OP's nice `x %in% c(4, 5)` to the clunkier `x == 4 | x == 5` syntax. I don't understand why you're presenting both.

Comment: And column names, like OP is trying to use, are generally safer to use than column indices.

Comment: I respect your assessment but disagree

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both `paste0()` and `ifelse()`, here is an example:

```
x <- paste0("Var", c(1,3,5))
newvar <- matrix(NA, nrow(df1), length(x))

for(j in 1:(length(x))){
  newvar[,j] <- ifelse(df1[ ,x[j]] %in% c(4,5), 1, 0)}

final.df <- data.frame(df1, 
                       newvar=ifelse(apply(newvar, 1, sum)>0, 1, 0
))
final.df

   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 newvar
1     3    5    2    1    5      1
2     3    3    1    1    5      1
3     2    3    3    2    4      1
4     2    1    4    3    5      1
5     3    4    1    4    2      0
6     5    1    3    5    1      1
7     4    1    5    5    1      1
8     1    5    4    3    3      1
9     2    3    2    1    1      0
10    3    2    5    2    5      1
```